# Can't test a mailer if the message is Cyrillic because of content_transfer_encoding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, mailer

Working on www.railstutorial.org/book Chapter 10

I created UserMailer and all the stuff and everything worked as it should.

Then I changed the text of the message to Cyrillic and test couldn't match "assert_match user.name, mail.body.encoded".

I figured out this:

The mail template can have a non-English word in the first paragraph. This

```
%p Здравствуйте, #{@user.name}!

%p Well

=link_to "Activate", edit_account_activation_url(@user.activation_token, email: @user.email)
```

works ok. In rails console I can see this (excerpt):

> Content-Type: text/html;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n
>
> \r\n=D0=97=D0=B4=D1=80=D0=B0=D0=B2=D1=81=D1=82=D0=B2=D1=83=D0=B9=D1=82=D0=B5=\r\n, Test User!\r\n
>
> \r\n
>
> Well
>
> \r\nhttp://localhost:3000/account_activations/yYZR6sI1_dy5ha3mBf1s=\r\niw/edit?email=3Dtest%40example.com\">Activate

If I add another non-Latin word somewhere (I added オープンソース to the second p), the encoding changes

```
Content-Type: text/html;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r    \n\r\nPHA+0JfQtNGA0LDQstGB0YLQstGD0LnRgtC1LCBUZXN0IFVzZXIhPC9wPgo8\r\ncD5XZWxsIOOCquODvOODl+ODs+OCveODvOOCuTwvcD4KPGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0\r\ncDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDozMDAwL2FjY291bnRfYWN0aXZhdGlvbnMveVlaUjZz\r\nSTFfZHk1aGEzbUJmMXNpdy9lZGl0P2VtYWlsPXRlc3QlNDBleGFtcGxlLmNv\r\nbSI+QWN0aXZhdGU8L2E+Cg==\r\n
```

and the test fails.

I tried to make the mailer use the encoding I like

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "me@here.is", content_transfer_encoding: "quoted-printable"
```

but without success.

What should I do?

Comment: Do you have `#encoding: utf-8` in 1st line of your file?

Comment: No, I don't. I don't believe it can help, but I'll give it a try. What file do you mean?

Comment: add before `class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base`

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think the problem is that Ruby can't match a string and base64-encoded text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assert_match user.name, mail.text_part.decoded`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21341877)

Comment: Just try to change `mail.body.encoded` to `mail.text_part.decoded`. And you will understand that my answer solves the problem.

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered as low quality, regardless they solve the problem or not. Plus "try to ..." does not really suggests you have a definitive answer. Why don't you just edit your answer and elaborate on how this solves the issue ?